# Ejabberd iex live throws 'bad "K" value: \ ' error

Tags: erlang, elixir, ejabberd

I installed `ejabberd` correctly( I configure it with `--enabled-all`) without any error. But when I want to run it in elixir mode I get this error:

```
# ejabberdctl iexlive
bad "K" value: \
Usage: beam.smp [flags] [ -- [init_args] ]
The flags are:

-a size        suggested stack size in kilo words for threads
               in the async-thread pool, valid range is [16-8192]
-A number      set number of threads in async thread pool,
               valid range is [0-1024]
-B[c|d|i]      c to have Ctrl-c interrupt the Erlang shell,
               d (or no extra option) to disable the break
               handler, i to ignore break signals
-c bool        enable or disable time correction
-C mode        set time warp mode; valid modes are:
               no_time_warp|single_time_warp|multi_time_warp
-d             don't write a crash dump for internally detected errors
               (halt(String) will still produce a crash dump)
-fn[u|a|l]     Control how filenames are interpreted
-hms size      set minimum heap size in words (default 233)
-hmbs size     set minimum binary virtual heap size in words (default 32768)
-hpds size     initial process dictionary size (default 10)
-K boolean     enable or disable kernel poll
-n[s|a|d]      Control behavior of signals to ports
               Note that this flag is deprecated!
-M<X> <Y>      memory allocator switches,
               see the erts_alloc(3) documentation for more info.
-pc <set>      Control what characters are considered printable (default latin1)
-P number      set maximum number of processes on this node,
               valid range is [1024-134217727]
-Q number      set maximum number of ports on this node,
               valid range is [1024-134217727]
-R number      set compatibility release number,
               valid range [16-18]
-r             force ets memory block to be moved on realloc
-rg amount     set reader groups limit
-sbt type      set scheduler bind type, valid types are:
-stbt type     u|ns|ts|ps|s|nnts|nnps|tnnps|db
-sbwt val      set scheduler busy wait threshold, valid values are:
               none|very_short|short|medium|long|very_long.
-scl bool      enable/disable compaction of scheduler load,
               see the erl(1) documentation for more info.
-sct cput      set cpu topology,
               see the erl(1) documentation for more info.
-secio bool    enable/disable eager check I/O scheduling,
               see the erl(1) documentation for more info.
-sub bool      enable/disable scheduler utilization balancing,
               see the erl(1) documentation for more info.
-sws val       set scheduler wakeup strategy, valid values are:
               default|legacy.
-swct val      set scheduler wake cleanup threshold, valid values are:
               very_lazy|lazy|medium|eager|very_eager.
-swt val       set scheduler wakeup threshold, valid values are:
               very_low|low|medium|high|very_high.
-sss size      suggested stack size in kilo words for scheduler threads,
               valid range is [4-8192]
-spp Bool      set port parallelism scheduling hint
-S n1:n2       set number of schedulers (n1), and number of
               schedulers online (n2), maximum for both
               numbers is 1024
-SP p1:p2      specify schedulers (p1) and schedulers online (p2)
               as percentages of logical processors configured and logical
               processors available, respectively
-t size        set the maximum number of atoms the emulator can handle
               valid range is [8192-0]
-T number      set modified timing level, valid range is [0-9]
-V             print Erlang version
-v             turn on chatty mode (GCs will be reported etc)
-W<i|w|e>      set error logger warnings mapping,
               see error_logger documentation for details
-zdbbl size    set the distribution buffer busy limit in kilobytes
               valid range is [1-2097151]
-zdntgc time   set delayed node table gc in seconds
               valid values are infinity or intergers in the range [0-100000000]

Note that if the emulator is started with erlexec (typically
from the erl script), these flags should be specified with +.
```

I can run the ejabberd server correctly. I created user and everything went well. I don't know the what is going wrong.

**My config** `Elixir 1.1.1` and `Erlang R18`.

Any comment is appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

I didn't pass any argument to it. What I did is as follows:

- Download source file and untar it.
- `./autogen` then `./configure --enable-all` then `make && make install`
- Everything went well. I can run start it successfully and stop it successfully. Also I can run it in live mode(`ejabberdctl live`).

The problem is when I run in with this `ejabberdctl iexlive`. Before I download the `ejabberd` I've installed `Elixir 1.1.1`. I don't know maybe this is the problem.

**UPDATE 2**

I went through the code of `ejabberdctl` and  I found the problem in this line of code:

```
ERLANG_OPTS=" +K $POLL -smp $SMP +P $ERL_PROCESSES $ERL_OPTIONS"
```

I change it to

```
ERLANG_OPTS=""
```

And it worked. But I don't know it will make any further problem or not. I will open an issue at their repository.

Comment: Dumb question.  What happens when you pass a "K"  argument on the command line?   Maybe you also want to specify the names/versions of all the software involved: e g I am running this on Elixir 1.1.1

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I updated my question.

Comment: I'd guess you need to figure out what those environment variables should be (look at the answer below) rather than just removing them.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `$POLL` variable in `+K $POLL` was not initialized correctly. The `+K` flag enables or disables the *kernel poll* functionality for the Erlang VM and its acceptable values are `true` or `false`.

The `ejabberdctl` shell script has some default values for `$POLL` and other Erlang VM options. Also it uses `ejabberdctl.cfg` config file and overwrites the default values with the ones which are included in this config file.

You should use `ejabberdctl.cfg` to set your desired options with uncommenting them as follows:

```
#' POLL: Kernel polling ([true|false])
#
# The kernel polling option requires support in the kernel.
# Additionally, you need to enable this feature while compiling Erlang.
#
# Default: true
#
POLL=true

#.
#' SMP: SMP support ([enable|auto|disable])
#
# Explanation in Erlang/OTP documentation:
# enable: starts the Erlang runtime system with SMP support enabled.
#   This may fail if no runtime system with SMP support is available.
# auto: starts the Erlang runtime system with SMP support enabled if it
#   is available and more than one logical processor are detected.
# disable: starts a runtime system without SMP support.
#
# Default: enable
#
SMP=enable
```

This file resides on `$ejabberd-installed-path/conf` if you installed ejabberd manually.

Comment: Wouldn't that also have to set those other environment variables as well?  The ERL_PROCESSES and ERL_OPTIONS environment variables?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Yes `ERL_PROCESSES` and `ERL_OPTIONS` as well as some other options are available in `ejabberdctl.cfg` config file.

Comment: @HamidrezaSoleimani Thanks I tried this solution but unfortunately it is not worked for me.